# Handle click on pagination link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this code and I want that after click li console.log display number of page. So I count my pages in pages const. I tryed do that on two way.
First:

```
const handlePageClick = (i) => {
    console.log(i);
}
const Pagination = ({pages}) => {
    let list = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
        list.push(<li key={i} onClick={handlePageClick(i)}>{i}</li>)
    }
    return list;
}
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="row">
            <ul>
                <Pagination pages={pages} />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

It run handlePageClick method after run the app, not after click.

Second method I tryed:

```
const linkRef = useRef(null);
const handlePageClick = (i) => {
    console.log(linkRef.current.innerText);
}
const Pagination = ({pages}) => {
    let list = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
        list.push(<li key={i} ref={linkRef} onClick={handlePageClick}>{i}</li>)
    }
    return list;
}
```

It display the last result all the times. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a function to your `onClick` handler, so you can call `handlePageClick` in that function, and pass your current value of `i` like this:

```js
const Pagination = ({pages}) => {
    let list = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
        list.push(<li key={i} ref={linkRef} onClick={() => handlePageClick(i)}>{i}</li>)
    }
    return list;
}
```

Notice how you're now passing `() => handlePageClick(i)` is now what you're passing to `onClick`. This is a function that gets executed when the click event happens, and it passes your current value of `i`

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt you need to use `onClick={() => handlePageClick(i)}`. This is because currently it is invoked on the app render because you are invoking the method so you create an infinite loop where the app is rendered -> the onClick event is invoked which causes a another render. Using an arrow function means you pass a function which is why you invoke it.